# What do you call "gift CDs" that you select music for manually?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Is there a special word or phrase for a CD with a carefully picked playlist you made for a particular person, often given as a gift?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is called a mix CD. [(From *mixtape*, originally)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixtape)

Comment: @Dan Abramov, I know this might look like an odd word, but the "mix tape" was incredibly iconic in the 80's, so mix CD is definately the most appropriate word for this.  If you even used "mix tape" (even though it's a CD) would be a comedic tip of the hat (IMO).

Comment: _mixed_ tapes is what they were called (though they sound exactly the same), and I think I hear people referring to a CD compilation as either that - a compilation - or still as a mixed tape.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to 'mix CD,' I've often just called them compilations.

The only problem with calling them simply 'compilations' is that it doesn't really differentiate from a commercially released compilation album, so you would have to say 'my own compilation' or 'compilation that I made.'

So it's not nearly as nice and succinct as simply 'mix CD,' but it still works.

Comment: I've never heard of a commercial compilation being called a 'mix CD'. And the ambiguity is resolved by saying something like "Here, I made you this mix CD."

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me. I meant that the problem with referring to your own mix CD as simply a 'compilation', is that you could be referring to a commercial one. I.e. "check out this compilation CD" is ambiguous, so you'd need, "listen to this compilation CD I made." However, what I think we're both trying to say is that "Listen to this mix CD" is unambiguous, because you wouldn't refer to a commercial compilation as a 'mix CD.'

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I see now what you meant.

Comment: No probs, I'll edit the answer to clarify for anyone else :)